# How to get ActiveRecord_Relation based on a ActiveRecord_Relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have models `User` `Course`

**User.rb**

```
has_many :courses
```

**Course.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

If I have a ActiveRecord_Relation `@users`, with a list of user.

How to get a ActiveRecord_Relation `@courses`, with a list of course based on `@users`

I know it can be done `@users.each do |user|` one by one. But is there a easier way to do it? like `@users.courses`?

Comment: yes, you can get user courses by calling @users.courses.

Comment: @Marv-C But I can't, it says `undefined method 'courses'`

Comment: can you show me your course controller

Comment: @Marv-C why it involves controller? you can assume there is no controller at all.

Comment: if that so, how do you assign/add user to a certain course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the #flat_map method from Ruby:

```
@users.flat_map(&:courses)
```

Answer (score 2):

`flat_map` is a good solution, but won't give you an ActiveRecord::Relation.

If you would like an ActiveRecord::Relation, you could build `@courses` like this.

```
@courses = Course.where(user_id: @users.select(:id))
```